# Canvas Element become small on simulator (Unity2d)

Tags: ios, canvas, unity-game-engine

I am developing a 2d game. I am on step where i have to make score things and button. I am doing this by canvas. It working fine on unity but when i test that on simulator all things become small and not showing in actual size. Can any one help me in this case.

[In Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACuYf.png)

[in Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zdJp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `Canvas` settings like below,

[image]

And for device like focus, change preview in `Game` tab from `Free Aspect` to any defined resolution. Like,

[image]

Then set sizes of your UI elements.

Comment: I am working in unity2d project and i have already done this thing but it's not working.